# With modern or near future technological capabilities, hypothetical ways to produce negative mass assuming it exists

Tags: science-based, materials

Assuming money and resources are unlimited, what could be some hypothetically feasible ways to produce negative matter with the current or near future technological capabilities of humans.

Comment: I'm glad you want to participate,  but you need to show us what your initial research about negative mass has shown you. How can anyone provide a basis for manufacturing something, if we're not sure it even exists?  Is there even a theoretical basis for negative matter? Otherwise, you can just make  up some plausible hand-waving and it'll be just as good as anything else.

Comment: What is *"negative matter"*? Please insert a brief description and link to a reference.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_mass

Comment: Guess I'll handwave it then.

Comment: After reading up a bit on it (I'm not an expert in this field by any means), I kind of get the impression that negative mass is more of a phenomena, or a *net* effect, than an observable quantity like mass is.

Comment: I think even "science based" is too much of a tag for this one. You are more or less asking for hand-waving here. Also, the wikipedia article you linked to actually does a pretty good job of listing the alternatives you want. (An exotic metamaterial, dark energy manipulation and a contraption utilizing Casimir effect.) So there is not really much to answer that you do not already know.

Answer (score 0):

Now when it comes to negative matter, we really don't know if it exists or what any of it's properties are. But for a second lets just assume what your talking about is matter with a negative mass; if this is the case then the matter probably absorbs gravity, without being affected by it, and can possibly travel faster then light. How and whether it reacts with normal matter is also unknown.

Now with all of these uncertainties about how negative matter works and if it exists or not you can't really create any process that sounds sound to create it; generally most people see such a problem as impossible to solve and would therefore just ignore it, but if you were to fully flesh out Negative matter and the physical laws governing it... Well, you may figure out a solution to your question and be able to create a lot more far future technologies out of the shenanigans you pulled to get to your destination. Also, i'd be perfectly happy to help along the way.